# Simple way to use concurrent threads in perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, concurrency

```
sub test {
   $val = shift;
   print $val * 2;
}

for $i (1..1000)
{
   test($i);
}
```

How can I get the calls to `test` to be executed in concurrent threads using [Thread::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/Thread-Pool-0.33/lib/Thread/Pool.pm) or [Thread::Pool::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~jwu/Thread-Pool-Simple-0.25/Simple.pm) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
use feature 'say';
use Thread::Pool::Simple;

sub test
{
    say shift;
    sleep(5);
}


my $pool = Thread::Pool::Simple->new (

    do => [\&test],

    min => 10,
    max => 20


);

$pool->add($_) for (1..50);
$pool->join;
say "Finished";
```

Comment: You may mark your own answer as accepted. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work